# Parsing CSV string with nodeJS without a library

Tags: node.js, firebase, csv, parsing, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a cloud function in firebase that parses csv files and adds them as a firestore document. Somehow, none of the libraries I try seem to work. Whenever I add a csv library, the function won't even deploy. therefore, I want to parse a CSV file without using a library. However, I cant seem to figure out how to parse it correctly when using maps and arrays. I have the following string in string type. Replaced some data with placeholders.

```
subject,contacts,dateStart,dateEnd,timeStart,timeEnd,isRecurring,frequence,location,room,visitors,sendInvite

Sollicitatie,[{"name":"<name here>","email":"<email here>","phoneNumber":"<phone number here>"}],28-09-2020,28-09-2020,13:00,14:00,true,yearly,<location here>,2,[{"name":"<name here>","email":"<email here>","visitorImage":"imgRef","visitorType":"Relation","phoneNumber":"<telephone here>","licencePlate":"<licencePlate>"}],true
```

I want to get this data in firestore as the following:

```
subject: subject,
contacts:[
    {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber
    },
    {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phoneNumber
    }
],
dateStart: dateStart,
dateEnd, dateEnd,
timeStart, timeEnd,
isRecurring, isRecurring,
frequence, frequence,
location: location,
room: room,
visitors:[
    {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber
    },
    {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phoneNumber
        //Whatever data also needs to be added
    }
]
```

Is there a library that will work/is there a problem with my package.json, or is there a script that will work? I tried to write a script that will do this, but it is far from working. I have tried the following and got the right strings, but I cant get the arrays the right way.

```
const convert = (from, to) => str => Buffer.from(str, from).toString(to);
              const hexToUtf8 = convert('hex', 'utf8');
              const string = hexToUtf8(contents);
              const data = string.split('\n');
              for(i=0;i<=data.length - 1;i++){
                if(i == 0){
                  continue;
                }
                const row = data[i];
                const rowValues = [];

                const elems = row.split(",");
                console.log(elems);

                var arrayParse;
                var parsing = 0;
                for(j=0;j<=elems.length - 1;j++){
                  const elem = elems[j];
                  if(parsing == 1){
                    arrayParse += "," + elem;
                    continue;
                  }else if(elem[0] == "["){
                    arrayParse += elem;
                    parsing = 1;
                    continue;
                  }else if(elem[elem.length - 1] == "]"){
                    arrayParse += elem;
                    parsing = 0;
                    rowValues.push(arrayParse);
                    arrayParse = "";
                    continue;
                  }else{
                    rowValues.push(elem);
                  }
                }
                console.log(rowValues);
```

Comment: You first state that you want to parse a CVS without a library, but then go on to ask if there are libraries to use.  Which is it?  I'll point out that requests for recommendations for offsite resources such as software libraries are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  If you have a specific problem using one of these libraries, that's what your question needs to focus on.

Comment: Please, clarify your question, as in this line `Is there a library that will work/is there a problem with my package.json, or is there a script that will work?` you ask three different questions, that are going in discordance with your initial lines.

Comment: I have reworked the question. It is a different string as I think this data is easier to parse now.